# How can I pinpoint which component is causing random shutdowns?

Tags: windows, hardware-failure, shutdown

**EDIT:** Looks like I have a bad  capacitor, check these pictures of [the motherboard on ECS website](http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/images/Products/large/A790GXM-AD3_580_2.jpg) and [my brown capacitor](http://imgur.com/a/mZV5K).. the one near the memory slots.

This could be causing the random shutdowns described below, right?

---

First of all, some specs that might help:

- Windows 10
- [ECS A790GXM](http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?CategoryID=1&DetailID=957&DetailName=Feature&MenuID=24&LanID=0)
- AMD Phenom II X4 995
- AMD Radeon R9 200 Series
- 10 GB of DDR3 (4+2+2+2)

This is my PC that has been by my side for the past 8~ years, and went through a lot of component upgrades & complete formats. Never had a problem like this.

Two days ago, after I booted it, I heard the CPU fan spike at max speed a few times every a minute or two, without any application/game open.. and after 3-5min, the computer shutdown.

It isn't a "complete" shutdown tho, the screen turned off, but the power led still on and the fans still spinning, but them computer was not "on" too... To recover from this I have to switch the power supply off and on. This keeps happening.

First I tried to find the problem on the software side and started uninstalling everything I could... and yet, the shutdown kept occurring after 5~ minutes of each power up.

I've also opened the case and removed all the components, cleared it, changed my CPU fan to a [Blizzard T2](http://www.coolermaster.com/cooling/cpu-air-cooler/blizzard-t2/) and replaced the thermal paste.. nothing changed.

I've also booted on an Ubuntu stick, and after a few minutes of benchmarking, it shutdown the same way it does on Windows. It also happened on safe mode.

And sometimes, it stays up for 10-30min without shutdown.

Right now, the CPU is at 50ºc and the fan at 2.2k RPM.

With all this, I'm pretty sure it's hardware related.

But **how can I pinpoint the component without replacing each one?** I don't have spare parts & can't afford a new one of each component.

Comment: (4+4+2+2) equals 12...

Comment: @Hennes my mistake, it's 4+2+2+2

Comment: Do you have access to other desktops? E.g. you could test the R9 200 in another PC...and see if that stays stable. Failing that the best way I see is checking the motherboard for blown capacitators (which often fail from old age). Failing that the regular testing with a minimal setup. E.g. motherboard, CPU and CPU fan... -> Should beep with no RAM error. Add 1 DIMM in the right socket.. Should move to beep code indicating 'no video'. Etc etc

Comment: @Hennes I do have another desktop around that's been off for a few years and I have no idea whats working on it.. I will move directly to the regular testing with minimal setup (did't knew about those steps) and get back when I'm done.

Comment: @Hennes looks like I have a bad capacitor near my memory slots.. check the main thread with updated information.